# Marklogic python lib for REST API

Tags: python, python-requests, marklogic

Markloggers out there!

I am working with Marklogic 6 and am a happy user of python.

Would anyone be able to tell me if there are efforts to create a python REST API library for Marklogic?
Similar to the java API?

Regards,

hugo

Comment: Do you mean something like XCC (which is not REST) but for Python? As far as I know, that doesn't exist. There is a universal REST API that would work in Python however: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/intro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing like the Java bindings exists right now, but I find that http://python-requests.org/ makes REST requests easy enough. Use `requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth` for authentication, and fill in the data using `jsons.dump` when you *don't* want a form post. There isn't much more to it.

Comment: Here's a [concrete example](https://github.com/jmakeig/modulesdb/blob/master/src/modulesclient.py) of connecting to a MarkLogic REST API instance using the (superb) Requests library that Mike recommends. This example only does the most basic CRUD, but you'll get the idea of how to wire things.

Answer (score 0):

If Python can call either shell or java then it can call xmlsh and you can do anything that is exposed as a ML XQuery call from a script.

http://www.xmlsh.org/ModuleMarkLogic

Answer (score 0):

A late answer to this -- there is now a community-driven project to create a [Python wrapper for the REST API](https://github.com/paul-hoehne/MarkLogic_Python). If you're interested, using that as a starting point and contributing improvements would move us closer to a full wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on one.  http://github.com/paul-hoehne/MarkLogic_Python.  But it's targeted at database and server management, not so much regular coding.